# PHP in_array for $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I hope this isn't too vague a question, but here goes.

I want to loop through the values stored in the `textfield_array` and see if they match any keys in the `$_POST` array. If they do I want to assign them to the `an_array`array.

It seems that there are no matches, although I know that there should be! Here's my code:

```
<?php
$an_array = array();

$textfield_array = array(
 'item_no', 'button_text', 'text_field', 'drop_down_title'
);

foreach( $textfield_array as $textfield ){
  if( in_array( $textfield, $_POST ) ){
    $an_array[$textfield] = $_POST[$textfield];
  }
}
?>
```

Am I being daft? Or misunderstanding how the `$_POST`array works?!

Comment: $_POST is an array like others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `in_array` works. `in_array` checks the values. You want to check the keys.

You can either use `isset`, or you can use `array_key_exists` (returns true if item exists with a value of `null`).

```
foreach ($textfield_array as $textfield) {
    if (isset($_POST[$textfield])) {
        $an_array[$textfield] = $_POST[$textfield];
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that. I did indeed misunderstand how in_array works! Thanks for setting me straight! R

Answer (score 1):

Use the `array_intersect` function.

```
$an_array = array_intersect(array_keys($_POST), $textfield_array);
```

Comment: This creates an array of keys, not an associative array as the OP originally asked for. Try `array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($textfield_array))`